# Burninate the [not-firing] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, burninate-request

[not-firing](/questions/tagged/not-firing) (45 questions) needs to be fired. It's a meta-tag where people tag things like

> [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa) [nstimer](/questions/tagged/nstimer) [nsthread](/questions/tagged/nsthread) [not-firing](/questions/tagged/not-firing)

Comment: I wouldn't call it a "meta-tag" so much as just an unspecified and pointless one. It's like "crash" or something; it's too broad to be useful.

Comment: But what if it's a career question? Oh wait....

Comment: @Pekka: Then it probably belongs on http://workplace.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why does everyone forget to [send the signal](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XfFNG.png)?